# Prevent file shortcuts from breaking when files are moved

Tags: nautilus

In Ubuntu (and Windows as well), I've noticed that whenever I create a file shortcut, and then move the file, the shortcut stops working, and becomes "broken". Is it possible to create a file shortcut in such a way that the shortcut will automatically point to the file's current location, instead of breaking whenever the file is moved?

Comment: This is a cross-platform issue, and not just an Ubuntu-specific issue, but I decided to post it here because I'm currently trying to solve this problem on Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like this program might do something like this, but it only works on Windows: http://download.cnet.com/Broken-Shortcut-Fixer/3000-2248_4-75222211.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ln` (link) command without the `-s` (symbolic) switch. The link will persist when moving the file within the file system.

```
ln foo baz
mv foo bar
```

`baz` will still link to the file originally known as `foo`.

Comment: There are some restrictions though: hard-links only work within the same filesystem and it's not possible to make hard-links to directories.

Comment: @ubfan1 Can you explain what `xx`, `lxx`, and `yy` are supposed to represent here? Should they each be substituted with file names, or left as-is?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I took the liberty of changing the placeholder to "foo bar baz" for intended clarity.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Is it possible to do this on Windows, as well as Unix-like operating systems?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Well, all POSIX systems as well as NTFS has support for [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). I have never used it in a Windows context personally, so I don't know how it works in practice, though. There is a command line tool `mklink` that creates hard links. If you want a GUI, you probably need third party software.